# Implementing Profile Photo Upload for Student Database

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am currently develop a student database system for my faculty. I am using the PHP together with MySQL. I am thinking to create an option for student to upload their profile photo but I could not find any proper instruction or tutorial of doing that.

Here's the code processing the file uploading:

```
<?php
 /* Script name: uploadFile.php
  * Description: Uploads a file via HTTP with a POST form. 
  */
  if(!isset($_POST[‘Upload’]))
  {
    include(“form_upload.inc”);
  }
  else   
  {
    if($_FILES[‘pix’][‘tmp_name’] == “none”) 
    {
      echo “<p style=’font-weight: bold’>
        File did not successfully upload. Check the 
            file size. File must be less than 500K.</p>”;
      include(“form_upload.inc”);
      exit();
    }
    if(!ereg(“image”,$_FILES[‘pix’][‘type’])) 
    {
      echo “<p style=’font-weight: bold’>
        File is not a picture. Please try another 
            file.</p>”;
      include(“form_upload.inc”);
      exit();
    }
    else   
    {
      $destination=’c:\data’.”\\”.$_FILES[‘pix’][‘name’];
      $temp_file = $_FILES[‘pix’][‘tmp_name’];
      move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$destination);
      echo “<p style=’font-weight: bold’>
        The file has successfully uploaded:
            {$_FILES[‘pix’][‘name’]} 
            ({$_FILES[‘pix’][‘size’]})</p>”; 
    }
  }
?>
```

Code for the file upload form:

```
<!-- Program Name: form_upload.inc
     Description:  Displays a form to upload a file -->
<html>
<head><title>File Upload</title></head>
<body>
<ol><li>Enter the file name of the product picture you 
        want to upload or use the browse button 
        to navigate to the picture file.</li>
    <li>When the path to the picture file shows in the
        text field, click the Upload Picture 
        button.</li>
</ol> 
<div align=”center”><hr />
<form enctype=”multipart/form-data” 
        action=”uploadFile.php” method=”POST”>
  <input type=”hidden” name=”MAX_FILE_SIZE” 
         value=”500000” />
  <input type=”file” name=”pix” size=”60” />
  <p><input type=”submit” name=”Upload” 
        value=”Upload Picture” />
</form>
</div></body></html>
```

I got the same outcome which I cant find the file that being uploaded and it is not being uploaded to the location as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the destination:

```
$destination=’c:\data’.”\”.$_FILES[‘pix’][‘name’];
```

Or, if this is not working, try to move the uploaded file somewhere near the script path, like:

```
$destination= dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES[‘pix’][‘name’];
```

If the second one works then is means, you have given a wrong directory for the upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first change your image path.
and than your datatype set to image in mysql manually,
it will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error messsage? Do the PHP user have write permissions to the upload directory?

Also, here's two advices possibly not related to your question:

- Don't use eregi in any new code. It is deprecated, which means it will be removed in a future version of PHP. Instead, use the preg_ functions, or just strpos in this case.
- Why would `$_FILES[‘pix’][‘tmp_name’]` ever be the string "none"?

Comment: "Not Found

The requested URL /Mentor Mentee System/Ã¢â‚¬ÂuploadFile.phpÃ¢â‚¬Â was not found on this server."

Comment: You probably have the wrong quote characters in your HTML file. Make sure you use `"` (ASCII number 34).